# Preferable way of datatables 1.10 column specific filtering?

Tags: datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I only recently started using jquery DataTables. For column filtering I'm looking into the original "columnfilter" plugin, which seems to have no recent updates though (except for some patches by numerous developers), and is also not adapted to version 1.10. What is the preferable way to do column specific filtering for version 1.10? (both client and server side)

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever used the client side and this code:

```
        $("#browse_1_div thead input").keyup( function () {
            /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */
            oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("thead input").index(this) );
        } );

        /*
         * Support functions to provide a little bit of 'user friendlyness' to the textboxes in
         * the footer
         */
        $("#browse_1_div thead input").each( function (i) {
            asInitVals[i] = this.value;
        } );

        $("#browse_1_div thead input").focus( function () {
            if ( this.className == "search_init_1" )
            {
                this.className = "";
                this.value = "";
            }
        } );

        $("#browse_1_div thead input").blur( function (i) {
            if ( this.value == "" )
            {
                this.className = "search_init_1";
                this.value = asInitVals[$("#browse_1_div thead input").index(this)];
            }
        } );
```

Comment: If I compare this to the columnFilter plugin, this seems like an awful lot of work...

Comment: it was, this is quite and old peace of code but it still works like it should.